# string matching in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

```
for interfacefile in `ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*`
```

I have following for loop in my shell script. now

```
ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.0  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:1
```

the problem is I want to grep only normal Ethernets... not like  `ifcfg-eth0.0` and `ifcfg-eth1:1`
this type of comma as well as DOT separated strings.

Comment: Please refrain from [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't something like `ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth[0-9]` suffice?

Comment: I would suggest `ifcfg-eth[0-9]` instead. Otherwise it loops through all numbers. With `[ ]` it just looks for files within this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
# enable extender pattern matching
shopt -s extglob

for interfaceFile in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth+([0-9])
```

Note that you don't need `ls` here. The shell will expand the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

A portable way for POSIX shells:

```
for if in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*; do
    [ -e "${if}" ] || continue
    if=${if##*/ifcfg-}
    case ${if#eth} in
        *[!0-9]*) continue ;;
    esac
    echo "${if}"
done
```

This will give you just the interface names (e.g. `eth0`, `eth1`, ...), if you are really after the full paths to the config files adapt the variable names accordingly.